# Make atexit registered function act according to exit status

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import atexit
import sys 

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    print "Good Bye"

print "Hello World"
#sys.exit(0) or sys.exit(1)
```

In the code above, `Good Bye` is executed every time it exits. Can I print a different message depending on the exit status? Something like if the exit status is 1, print `FATAL: Good Bye`

I checked `sys.exitfunc` too but that also doesn't seem to support this? Isn't this something basic that should be supported or is there something better to use for cases like these. Is using a wrapper function to exit my program the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkey-patch `sys.exit` pretty easily:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.my_exit = sys.exit
>>> def func(status):
...     if status:
...        print "Fatal!"
...     sys.my_exit(status)
... 
>>> sys.exit = func
>>> sys.exit(1)
Fatal!
```

Of course, this only runs if `sys.exit` is actually called from somewhere within the code ...

You could alternatively wrap your main function in a try/except:

```
import sys
def main():
    pass
    sys.exit(2) #comment this out, or change the exit status to 0 to test.

try:
    main()
except SystemExit as e:
    if e.args[0]:  #non-zero exit status
        print "Failed"
    else:
        print "Success"
    raise
else:
    print "Success"
```

Comment: Basically, I want two separate messages "Run finished syccessfully" and "Aborted". So, in this code, there is no way to print "Run finished successfully" without actually calling sys.exit(0).

Comment: @shadyabhi -- We need to test for the case where the user puts in `sys.exit(0)` -- That still raises `SystemExit` and wouldn't print `"success"` if we didn't do it explicitly.  Ultimately, this seems like something that would be useful to include in `atexit` as a decorator -- Or maybe in `contextlib` -- `with exit_status(main,func_that_gets_exit_status): ...`